# Non-Incrementing Cells(row,col).Value Variable during Dictionary For Loop Search

Tags: excel, vba, dictionary

Good evening. About five months ago I put together a dictionary search and print function that goes through a client's excel sheet looking for specific headers and printing out the entirety of that column below that header, to my own sheet. The code below worked (almost) perfectly. Clients data would occur in random columns starting at A and going through as many columns as needed. I would paste the chosen columns into my sheet from columns M32 to T32.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Unprotect_Me

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim filename As String, colName As String
    Dim LRow As Long, LCol As Long
    Dim pColName As String
    Dim sCell As Range, PRng As Range
    Dim col As Long, pCol As Long
    Dim dict As New Scripting.Dictionary
    Dim cnt As Integer

    MsgBox "Ensure plan includes MD/INC/AZM/TVD/NS/EW/VS/DLS"
    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)                                                                          

        .AllowMultiSelect = False                                                                                           
        .Filters.Add "Excel Files", "*.xlsx; *.xlsm; *.xls; *.xlsb", 1                                                      

        If .Show Then

            filename = .SelectedItems(1)                                                                                    

            Set wb = Workbooks.Open(filename:=filename)                                                                     

            dict.Add "MD", 1
            dict.Add "Measured Depth", 1
            dict.Add "Inc", 2
            dict.Add "Inc.", 2
            dict.Add "Incl", 2
            dict.Add "Incl.", 2
            dict.Add "Inclination", 2
            dict.Add "Az", 3
            dict.Add "Azm", 3
            dict.Add "Azi", 3
            dict.Add "Azim.", 3
            dict.Add "Azimuth", 3
            dict.Add "TVD", 4
            dict.Add "Total Vertical Depth", 4
            dict.Add "Total Vertical Depth (TVD)", 4
            dict.Add "N(+)", 5
            dict.Add "NS", 5
            dict.Add "N/S", 5
            dict.Add "N.Offset", 5
            dict.Add "N. Offset", 5
            dict.Add "Local N/-S", 5
            dict.Add "Local N Coord", 5
            dict.Add "E(+)", 6
            dict.Add "EW", 6
            dict.Add "E/W", 6
            dict.Add "E.Offset", 6
            dict.Add "E. Offset", 6
            dict.Add "Local E/-W", 6
            dict.Add "Local E Coord", 6
            dict.Add "VS", 7
            dict.Add "V.Sect.", 7
            dict.Add "V Sect", 7
            dict.Add "Vertical Section", 7
            dict.Add "DLS", 8
            dict.Add "DL/100'", 8
            dict.Add "Dogleg", 8
            dict.Add "Dogleg Severity", 8


            If Not IsEmpty(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("5D-Lite").Range("M32")) Then
                LRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 13).End(xlUp).Row                                                                  
                LCol = Cells(LRow, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column                                                      
                ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("5D-Lite").Range("M32:" & Col_Letter(LCol) & LRow).ClearContents                    
            End If

            With wb.Worksheets(1)
                For i = 0 To dict.Count - 1
                    Set sCell = .Range("A2:R50").Find(What:=dict.keys(i), LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                    SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)                                           
                    If Not sCell Is Nothing Then
                        col = sCell.Column                                                                                  
                        pCol = cnt + 13                                                                                     
                        cnt = cnt + 1                                                                                       
                        colName = Split(.Cells(, col).Address, "$")(1)                                                      
                        pColName = Split(.Cells(, pCol).Address, "$")(1)                                                    
                        LRow = FindLastNumeric()                                                                           
                        Set PRng = .Range(sCell.Address & ":" & colName & LRow)                                             
                           wb.Activate
                           wb.Worksheets(1).Range(PRng.Address).Copy ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("5D-Lite").Range(pColName & "32") 'Copy contents of selected file to the 5D sheet
                    End If
                Next
                Range("M32:T32").HorizontalAlignment = xlRight
                Range("M33:T" & LRow + 33).NumberFormat = "0.00"                                                            
                wb.Close SaveChanges:=False                                                                                 
                Set wb = Nothing
            End With

        Else
        MsgBox "No Plan Selected"
        End If
    End With
Protect_Me
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

However I have come upon one client that uses an unconventional formatting where they double their header titles. As an example on the client's sheet Row 32 will have "Measured Depth", and Row 33 has "MD" triggering both dictionary definitions and causing the copy to occur twice (for each column) and screwing up the format. I thought this was an easy solve by inputting the following for loop

```
                        For j = (dict(dict.keys(i)) + 12) To 30
                            MsgBox dict(Cells(32, j).Value)
                            If dict(dict.keys(i)) = dict(Cells(32, j).Value) Then
                                cnt = cnt - 1
                                MsgBox "Skipped it"
                                Exit For
                            Else
                                wb.Activate
                                wb.Worksheets(1).Range(PRng.Address).Copy ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("5D-Lite").Range(pColName & "32") 'Copy contents of selected file to the 5D sheet

                                Exit For
                            End If
                        Next
```

(Full code block below) However there is an unusual bug I can't seem to isolate. The code block picks up the first instance of "MD"and prints the following column perfectly. It then skips the instance of "Measured Depth" as desired and moves to the next headers (Inclinations). While cycling through "Measured Depth" the `dict(Cells(32, j).Value)` does exactly what I expect it to do, and automatically updates to the value of MD (since MD was previously printed in that cell). The code goes on to pick up the first INC and copies its data into the second column as desired, but here is where the issue occurs. For the second "Inclination" header cycle, while var j increments to the correct number (14 for column N), and despite "INC" being in Cell(32,14), the `dict(Cells(32, j).Value)` returns "Empty" despite not having done so for any of the previous iterations. This then causes the data to be duplicated re-copying it into the third column, causing the rest of the data to be offset inappropriately.

I imagine this is just a fundamental misunderstanding of how `Cells(32, j).Value` works on my part, but after the better part of 6 hours stepping through and watching the various variables increment, I can't for the life of me isolate it.

Full code block:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Unprotect_Me

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim filename As String, colName As String
    Dim LRow As Long, LCol As Long
    Dim pColName As String
    Dim sCell As Range, PRng As Range
    Dim col As Long, pCol As Long
    Dim dict As New Scripting.Dictionary
    Dim cnt As Integer

    MsgBox "Ensure plan includes MD/INC/AZM/TVD/NS/EW/VS/DLS"
    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)                                                                          

        .AllowMultiSelect = False                                                                                           
        .Filters.Add "Excel Files", "*.xlsx; *.xlsm; *.xls; *.xlsb", 1                                                      

        If .Show Then

            filename = .SelectedItems(1)                                                                                    

            Set wb = Workbooks.Open(filename:=filename)                                                                     

            dict.Add "MD", 1
            dict.Add "Measured Depth", 1
            dict.Add "Inc", 2
            dict.Add "Inc.", 2
            dict.Add "Incl", 2
            dict.Add "Incl.", 2
            dict.Add "Inclination", 2
            dict.Add "Az", 3
            dict.Add "Azm", 3
            dict.Add "Azi", 3
            dict.Add "Azim.", 3
            dict.Add "Azimuth", 3
            dict.Add "TVD", 4
            dict.Add "Total Vertical Depth", 4
            dict.Add "Total Vertical Depth (TVD)", 4
            dict.Add "N(+)", 5
            dict.Add "NS", 5
            dict.Add "N/S", 5
            dict.Add "N.Offset", 5
            dict.Add "N. Offset", 5
            dict.Add "Local N/-S", 5
            dict.Add "Local N Coord", 5
            dict.Add "E(+)", 6
            dict.Add "EW", 6
            dict.Add "E/W", 6
            dict.Add "E.Offset", 6
            dict.Add "E. Offset", 6
            dict.Add "Local E/-W", 6
            dict.Add "Local E Coord", 6
            dict.Add "VS", 7
            dict.Add "V.Sect.", 7
            dict.Add "V Sect", 7
            dict.Add "Vertical Section", 7
            dict.Add "DLS", 8
            dict.Add "DL/100'", 8
            dict.Add "Dogleg", 8
            dict.Add "Dogleg Severity", 8


            If Not IsEmpty(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("5D-Lite").Range("M32")) Then
                LRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 13).End(xlUp).Row                                                                  
                LCol = Cells(LRow, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column                                                      
                ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("5D-Lite").Range("M32:" & Col_Letter(LCol) & LRow).ClearContents                    
            End If

            With wb.Worksheets(1)
                For i = 0 To dict.Count - 1
                    Set sCell = .Range("A2:R50").Find(What:=dict.keys(i), LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                    SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)                                           
                    If Not sCell Is Nothing Then
                        col = sCell.Column                                                                                  
                        pCol = cnt + 13                                                                                     
                        cnt = cnt + 1                                                                                       
                        colName = Split(.Cells(, col).Address, "$")(1)                                                      
                        pColName = Split(.Cells(, pCol).Address, "$")(1)                                                    
                        LRow = FindLastNumeric()                                                                           
                        Set PRng = .Range(sCell.Address & ":" & colName & LRow)                                             

                         For j = (dict(dict.keys(i)) + 12) To 30
                            If dict(dict.keys(i)) = dict(Cells(32, j).Value) Then
                                cnt = cnt - 1
                                Exit For
                            Else
                                wb.Activate
                                wb.Worksheets(1).Range(PRng.Address).Copy ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("5D-Lite").Range(pColName & "32") 'Copy contents of selected file to the 5D sheet
                                Exit For

                            End If
                        Next
                    End If
                Next
                Range("M32:T32").HorizontalAlignment = xlRight
                Range("M33:T" & LRow + 33).NumberFormat = "0.00"                                                            
                wb.Close SaveChanges:=False                                                                                 
                Set wb = Nothing
            End With

        Else
        MsgBox "No Plan Selected"
        End If
    End With
Protect_Me
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Any help in tracking down this problem would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It might be better to "pre-scan" the range to check how many distinct rows you find the headers in, then if there are multiple rows just pick one of those rows to scan for the actual transfer.  Assuming for "single-header row" files all of the headers are in one row, and for double-header files the contents of both rows match items in your dictionary, so it doesn't matter which row you pick.  Also - converting numeric column indexes to letters is pretty awkward and you don't need to do it if you use `Cells(rowNum, ColNum)` to refer to ranges

Comment: What is `FindLastNumeric` ?

Comment: @TimWilliams My apologies. Find last Numeric is a function that finds the cell with the final numeric value in the column.
 
`Function FindLastNumeric()
LastNumeric = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Do Until IsNumeric(Range("A" & LastNumeric).Text) Or LastNumeric = 1
    LastNumeric = LastNumeric - 1
Loop
FindLastNumeric = LastNumeric
End Function`

Comment: Which sheet is that operating on?  Seems like you call it multiple times in the loop, but it always looks at the same column, so could it be moved out of the `i` loop?  For sheets with two header rows, is it only some keys which will match header row 2, or will the number of matches be the same for both rows?

Comment: It is operating on the client's sheet on the column that is determined to match one of the dictionary keys. It's called every time in the loop because the client's data might be different lengths (different number of rows) depending on the header in question.

Comment: But it only looks at ColA?

Comment: Mm. Hello there. Good catch. Not the problem causer but it can definitely be moved out of the loop. To answer your previous question for sheets with two header rows all rows will have two key matches.

Comment: @TimWilliams Although, all that aside, from a purely programmatic standpoint I am still wondering why, while tracking each variable, when j=14, and there is a value in Cell(32,14) the dict(cell(32,14)).Value is returning Empty.

Comment: I can't really answer that without seeing the source worksheet...

Comment: I can take a look but not until later today.

Comment: Interesting. It's a case sensitivity issue. Somehow calling the `dict.keys(i)` during the `set sCell` portion of the code was case in-sensitive. "INC" would trigger the "Inc" key. but while calling `dict(dict.keys(i))` the dictionary became case-sensitive so that it couldn't reverse locate the item due to INC != Inc. Setting `dict.CompareMode = TextCompare` solved the issue entirely.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was caused by an odd case sensitivity issue during dictionary lookup. While the function was case-insentive while looking up the key (e.g.: INC = Inc) the item lookup function `dict(dict.keys(i))` could not match Inc to INC. By adding

```
dict.CompareMode = TextCompare
```

after initializing the dictionary, the problem was sorted out.